configuring php pm on the server
I am not a php developer and I do not know how to configure the server, but I have such a problem. In the statistics of RAM and processor on my server, some slides are displayed (CPU https://disk.yandex.ru/i/BvtYfNCUGmAb1A and RAM https://disk.yandex.ru/i/WgSEYqJKU0gZFg).
There are 4 running applications on the server, 2 php and 2 js, and it has 8 Cores and 16 GB of RAM.
There are such lines in php logs:
WARNING: [pool web] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 10 idle, and 31 total children
WARNING: [pool web] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 53 total children
WARNING: [pool web] server reached pm.max_children setting (64), consider raising it

Sometimes there are such
NOTICE: Terminating ...
NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 4182079
NOTICE: ready to handle connections
NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms

ps -ylC php-fpm --sort:rss
S   UID     PID    PPID  C PRI  NI   RSS    SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
S     0    1623    1532  0  80   0 22332 20315 ep_pol ?        00:00:02 php-fpm
S    33  224785    1623  0  80   0 32404 24662 inet_c ?        00:00:03 php-fpm
S    33    2094    1623  0  80   0 33164 25185 inet_c ?        00:00:03 php-fpm
S    33    2093    1623  0  80   0 34428 25171 inet_c ?        00:00:04 php-fpm

free -hl
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       7.1Gi       2.2Gi        83Mi       6.5Gi       8.3Gi
Low:            15Gi        13Gi       2.2Gi
High:             0B          0B          0B
Swap:          4.0Gi       8.0Mi       4.0Gi

Current pm
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

Perhaps this problem can be fixed by configuring pm max_children, start_servers, min_spare_servers, max_spare_servers, but I'm afraid to make it worse.
If I make these settings:
pm.max_children = 6
pm.start_servers = number of processor cores х 4
pm.min_spare_servers = number of processor cores х 2
pm.max_spare_servers = number of processor cores х 4

Can I break everything?
What happens if you put more pm?
Could it be that the php application internally calls itself and because of this overflows the pm, and later resets when it reaches 64?
UPD:
Current pm2:
pm.max_children = 64
pm.start_servers = 24
pm.min_spare_servers = 16
pm.max_spare_servers = 24
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
pm.max_requests = 2500


The numbers you currently have in the config are really low.
Yes - you should do the change you described.
Looks like your processes each use about 35MB, so you have plenty of RAM left

Thanks for the reply. I was looking at the wrong place when I asked the question.
Current pm2:
pm = dynamic;
pm.max_children = 64;
pm.start_servers = 24;
pm.min_spare_servers = 16;
pm.max_spare_servers = 24;
pm.max_requests = 2500.
Could it be that the php application internally calls itself and because of this overflows the pm, and later resets when it reaches 64?
